# Как лучше преобразовать тип string в тип int? (C++ 17)

Tags: c++, c++17

Знаю, что в C++ 17 имеются несколько способов преобразования различных типов к другим типам.

Например если подключить класс *string*, то можно воспользоваться многими методами оттуда, такими как **to_string()** или же **stoi()**. Проблема у меня возникает когда пытаюсь превратить строку, содержащую вначале цифру '0'(03, например) в целое число. Этот самый **stoi()** превращает изначальную строку "03" в число 3. А если 'доклеить' ноль в начало, то потом все равно приходится превращать это в число, так как возвести в квадрат строку невозможно и неправильно.

И это для меня важно, я пишу Генератор Псевдо - Случайных Чисел(PRNG) методом возведения в квадрат и вырезания срединных чисел. Пробовал еще и **atoi()**, тоже не получается

Comment: Непонятно, чем не устраивает stoi

Comment: А во что должно превращаться 03, если не в 3?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. При чем здесь этот 0 вообще?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для решения данной задачи строки вообще не нужны.

```
36*36=1296
середина
1296/10 = 129
129 % 100 = 29
```